# getting pygame keyboard events as integers

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I am making a math game and I want the user to be able to enter the answer. Do I have to do something like this for each number.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    blahblahblah
    quit event
    if event.key == K_1:
        str(answer + 1)
```

Is there a way to get keyboard events and if they are numbers turn them into integers. Perhaps a build in method?

Answer (score 2):

K_1 is already an integer (49). They are just constants of integers representing a specific key. So in your case, if you want to create an integer '1' when the player presses K_1 and '2' when the player presses K_2, all you have to do is:

```
answer = event.key - 48
```